# How to force a running t-sql query (half done) to commit?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database on Sql Server 2008 R2.
On that database a delete query on 400 Million records, has been running for 4 days , but I need to reboot the machine. How can I force it to commit whatever is deleted so far? I want to reject that data which is deleted by running query so far.
But problem is that query is still running and will not complete before the server reboot.

Note : I have not set any isolation / begin/end transaction for the query. The query is running in SSMS studio.

If machine reboot or I cancelled the query, then  database will go in recovery mode  and it will recovering for next 2 days, then I need to re-run the delete and it will cost me another 4 days.

I really appreciate any suggestion / help or guidance in this.
I am novice user of sql server.

Thanks in Advance
Regards

Comment: This is a good question with, unfortunately, no good answer. It is surprising that bulk DML is still troublesome in the year 2014.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to stop SQL Server from trying to bring the database into a transactionally consistent state. Every single statement is implicitly a transaction itself (if not part of an outer transaction) and is executing either all or nothing. So if you either cancel the query or disconnect or reboot the server, SQL Server will from transaction log write the original values back to the updated data pages.

Next time when you delete so many rows at once, don't do it at once. Divide the job in smaller chunks (I always use 5.000 as a magic number, meaning I delete 5000 rows at the time in the loop) to minimize transaction log use and locking.

```
set rowcount 5000
delete table
while @@rowcount = 5000
    delete table
set rowcount 0
```

Comment: Thanks Dean for  your comments . One more information I want to add is  : My database is in Simple recovery mode

Comment: It makes no difference. I updated the answer with a scipt showing how to delete 5000 by 5000 rows.

Comment: @user3380585 You may find that changing to bulk logged mode to run your delete statements improves performance, too, but do not do that on a production system unless it is during downtime. Also consider using the `TRUNCATE TABLE` command if you need to delete an entire table and do not want the transaction logged. Still, deleting 400 million rows isn't actually that much. I wonder if something else is going on and the transaction is blocked.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to run a query in chunks . I AM TRYNING to delete duplicate records based on MyKey. how to tune this"
WITH cte AS (
SELECT [ID]
      ,[F2]
      ,[F3]
      ,[F8]
      ,[F14]
      ,[F29]
      ,[F31]
      ,[F43]
      ,[F44]
      ,[F45]
      ,[F46]
      ,[F47]
      ,[F48]
      ,[F49]
      ,[F50]
      ,[F52]
      ,[F53]
      ,[F54]
      ,[F55]
      ,[F56]
      ,[F57]
      ,[F58]
      ,[F59]
      ,[F63]
         ,  row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY  MyKey
            ORDER BY    MyKey ) AS [rn]
  FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable]
)
DELETE cte WHERE [rn] > 1
"

Comment: @BaconBits Changing recovery model from simple to bulk won't help a bit.

Comment: @dean Yes, you're right.  That wasn't there when I started typing. :)

Comment: Create a cursor `for select MyKey from myTable', and delete in the loop one value of MyKey at the time. This will work if there is a convinient number of rows for each MyKey; otherwise, find some other value to loop over.

Answer (score 3):

If you are deleting that many rows you may have a better time with truncate. Truncate deletes all rows from the table very efficiently. However, I'm assuming that you would like to keep some of the records in the table. The stored procedure below backs up the data you would like to keep into a temp table then truncates then re-inserts the records that were saved. This can clean a huge table very quickly.

Note that truncate doesn't play well with Foreign Key constraints so you may need to drop those then recreate them after cleaned.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[deleteTableFast] ( 
@TableName VARCHAR(100),
@WhereClause varchar(1000)) 
AS 
BEGIN
-- input:
-- table name: is the table to use
-- where clause: is the where clause of the records to KEEP

declare @tempTableName varchar(100);
set @tempTableName = @tableName+'_temp_to_truncate';

-- error checking
if exists (SELECT [Table_Name] FROM Information_Schema.COLUMNS WHERE [TABLE_NAME] =(@tempTableName)) begin
print 'ERROR: already temp table ... exiting'
return
end
if not exists (SELECT [Table_Name] FROM Information_Schema.COLUMNS WHERE [TABLE_NAME] =(@TableName)) begin
print 'ERROR: table does not exist ... exiting'
return
end

-- save wanted records via a temp table to be able to truncate
exec ('select * into '+@tempTableName+' from '+@TableName+' WHERE '+@WhereClause);
exec ('truncate table '+@TableName);
exec ('insert into '+@TableName+' select * from '+@tempTableName);
exec ('drop table '+@tempTableName);

end
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You must know D(Durability) in [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) first before you understand why database goes to Recovery mode.

Generally speaking, you should avoid long running SQL if possible. Long running SQL means more lock time on resource, larger transaction log and huge rollback time when it fails.

Consider divided your task some id or time. For example, you want to insert large volume data from TableSrc to TableTarget, you can write query like

```
DECLARE @BATCHCOUNT INT = 1000;
DECLARE @Id INT = 0;
DECLARE @Max = ...;
WHILE Id < @Max
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableTarget
    FROM TableSrc
    WHERE PrimaryKey >= @Id AND @PrimaryKey < @Id + @BatchCount;
    SET @Id = @Id + @BatchCount;
END
```

It's ugly more code and more error prone. But it's the only way I know to deal with huge data volume.